# How can I create a google spreadsheet from a template?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a website which is using the Google Drive and Spreadsheets APIs. What I want to do is to create a spreadsheets on the user's Google Drive if no spreadsheets with a specific criteria is found.
The spreadsheet should be a copy of a public spreadsheet on my Google Drive.

```
/**
* Find the right file.
*/
function findFile() {
  appendPre('Finding file…')
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    "q": "fullText contains 'Omregning fra klokketimer (60 minutter) til skoletimer (45 minutter) (Summering av fravær i Skolearena er i klokketimer)'"
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    if (!resp.error) {
      console.log(resp);
      spreadSheetId = getID(resp.items);
    } else if (resp.error.code == 401) {
      // Access token might have expired.
      checkAuth();
    } else {
      appendPre('An error occured: ' + resp.error.message);
    }
  });
}

/**
* Find ID of the right file or create a file if none exist and return ID
*/
function getID(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      return items[i].id;
    }
  }
  // Code to create spreadsheet from public spreadsheet here
}
```

I've tried looking at the API docs and searching with google, but I have not found anything about how to do this. I really hope that it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried to use [template](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create#create_a_new_file_from_the_drive_ui) [variable substitution](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#open_url) to contruct the request URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually easier than i thought:

```
function copyFile(id, name) {
  var body = {'title': name};
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.copy({
    'fileId': id,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('Copy ID: ' + resp.id);
    return resp.id;
  });
}
```